# Windows 10 Universal Audio Background Player - unable to register for background task: Run Method Doesn't fire

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, c#-5.0

Developing **Visual Studio 2015 RC - Windows 10** universal app for background audio player.

I have followed the following steps.

Created 3 projects.

1. MusicPlayer (Blank App - Windows Universal Project)
2. Playlist (Class Library - Windows Universal Project)
3. AudioBackgroundAgent (Windows Runtime Component - Windows Universal Project)

Followed same steps as https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319

Everything is ok, except I'm unable to register and fire background task Run method.

Please suggest me, What are the steps to be followed to register and fire background task Run method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May need to add the entry point in the Package.manifest for example here's the section you will probably need based on a similar example:

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="SampleBackgroundAudioTask.MyBackgroundAudioTask">
    <BackgroundTasks>
    <Task Type="audio" />
    </BackgroundTasks>
  </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

Also you may need to add a reference to your Agent project to the main project in this case 3. AudioBackgroundAgent must be referenced by 1. MusicPlayer

Comment: I did that too..Thanks :). That was not the problem. Problem was with the bool result = SererInitialized.WaitOne(2000); just increased the time. It worked fine.

Comment: Good to know what was up, something bound to run into as well when developing with background tasks

Comment: If increasing the wait timeout caused it to "work" then you probably have a bigger problem. What happens on a slower device that takes even longer? Why do you need to wait at all?